# Is there a date-time string format that will work in all major browsers (including IE Quirks mode) when using javascript Date.parse()?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to find a date-string format that will allow me to use Date.parse to get a valid date.  (I'm using a third party javascript library that is using Date.parse)

I've tried using an ISO formated date string like

```
Date.parse("2011-05-06T17:22:11.234");
```

but IE Quirks mode returns NaN.

The following works in Quirks mode, but not in FireFox:

```
Date.parse("2011/05/06T17:22");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: perhaps you could try using the date.js library. it overrides Date.parse and will parse almost anything into a pretty reliable date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
var t=new Date("2011/05/06 17:22");
alert(t);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm getting NaN as a result of this parse in IE and FF.

Comment: OK, I understand now.  I think I can solve my problem this way:  by creating a date object with your specified format before doing the Date.parse.

Comment: Actually, Date.parse("2011/05/06 17:22") works properly in FF and IE (standards and Quirks).  Special bonus kudos, too, as it works in Safari and chrome!

Comment: In which timezone is it parsed?

Comment: @Bergi  -2 gmt. running under chrome

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting it in my local timezone (GMT+2) as well under Opera.

Answer (score 2):

MDN refers to http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime and the current Firefox version does support this, but Chrome does not. Chrome wants you to leave out the "T" character. I haven't checked IE.

I've gone back to using UNIX epoch timestamps :)